# How would you label an audio track as a "Japanese Surround 5.1" in MP4Box or ffmpeg

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, mp4

I have tried several methods of trying to label the track such as using

```
MP4Box -lang 3=jpn file.mp4
```

and then did

```
MP4Box -name 3="5.1 Surround" file.mp4
```

and the file in VLC keeps it's label only showing

```
Track 2 [Japanese]
```

Sidenote: Yes I am selecting the right audio track I want to rename which is track 3 in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add metadata in this manner using FFmpeg. To demonstrate this I created a test file with the following properties:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661) [...]
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo,
```

To add a tag to the audio stream using FFmpeg try the following syntax:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c copy \
          -metadata:s:a:0 language=jpn -metadata:s:a:0 title="5.1 Surround" \
          testing.mp4
```

Some notes:

1. `-c copy`: copy both streams without encoding to a new container. FFmpeg will not actually place the tags without this process.
2. `-metadata:s:a:0`: add the metatdata to : the **s**tream : **a**udio : first audio track. Note that this is 0, not 1 as you might expect. Note also that the `-metadata` option must be repeated with each extra metadata added.

Respect for these tags is a bit hit and miss across media players but tags added in this manner are picked up by `mediainfo`...

**References:**

- [FFmpeg Documentation: Main Options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)